# A Submanifold $M$ of $\Bbb C^N$

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, several-complex-variables

I have a **Proposition** in my book, and I write here:

> For every $p \in M$, with $M$ be a hypersurface in $\Bbb C^N$ the following hold.
>
> \begin{align*}
> \mathcal V_p &= \left \{ X \in \Bbb C T_p M \colon J(X)=-iX \right \},\tag{1}\\
> \mathcal V_p \oplus \overline{\mathcal V_p} &=\Bbb C T_{p}^{c}M, \tag{2} \\
> \mathcal V_p &=\left \{ X+iJ(X) \colon   X \in  T_{p}^{c}M  \right \},\tag{3} \\
> \operatorname{Re} \mathcal V_p &=T_{p}^{c}M, \tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> where $\operatorname{Re} \mathcal V_p=\left \{ X+\overline{X} \colon  X \in \mathcal V_p \right \}.$
>
> With a real linear mapping $J$ ($J^2=-Id$) from $T_p\Bbb C^N$ into itself determined by 
>   $$J \left (\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_j} \mid_p   \right )= \dfrac{\partial }{\partial y_j} \mid_p , J \left (\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y_j} \mid_p   \right )= -\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_j} \mid_p ,\ ~~~~ j=\overline{1,N}.$$

***PROOF***

> A direct calculation shows that
>   $$J\left ( \dfrac{\partial }{\partial Z_j} \right )=i\dfrac{\partial }{\partial Z_j},\ J\left ( \dfrac{\partial }{\partial \overline{Z_j}} \right )=-i\dfrac{\partial }{\partial \overline{Z_j}}. \tag{5}$$
>   Thus, we obtain
>   $$
> J\left ( \operatorname{Re}\left (\sum_{j=1}^{N}c_j\dfrac{\partial }{\partial \overline{Z_j}}  \right ) \right )=\operatorname{Im}\left (\sum_{j=1}^{N}c_j\dfrac{\partial }{\partial \overline{Z_j}}  \right ).\tag{6}$$

---

And here's my trouble: I don't understand Why do we have $(5),\ (6)$?

On the other hand, Why the Proposition easily follows from these relations?

Can anyone write the details?

Thanks!

Comment: What is "my book" ?

Comment: Can you see here (page 8):  http://www.mediafire.com/download/82lgnk9lu9pl8ce/M.+Salah+Baouendi%2C+Peter+Ebenfelt%2C+Linda+Preiss+Rothschild-Real+submanifolds+in+complex+space+and+their+mappings-Princeton+University+Press.djvu

Comment: I'm sorry I mean that Baouendi's book :D and can you post  your hint?

Comment: Dear @kimtahe6, I have no hint: I just wanted to understand the notations!

Comment: OMG! Anyway, thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\frac{\partial}{\partial Z_j},\,\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{Z}_j}$ are the Wirtinger derivatives,

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial Z_j} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right),\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{Z}_j} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right).$$

Then by linearity of $J$ we compute

$$J\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial Z_j}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(J\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right) - i J\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right) = i\frac{\partial}{\partial Z_j},$$

and

$$J\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{Z}_j}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(J\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right) + i J\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right) = -i\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{Z}_j}.$$

From that, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
J\left(\operatorname{Re}\sum c_j\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{Z}_j}\right)
&= \frac{1}{2} J\left(\sum c_j\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{Z}_j} + \sum \overline{c}_j \frac{\partial}{\partial Z_j}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \left(\sum c_j\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{Z}_j}-\overline{c}_j\frac{\partial}{\partial Z_j}\right)\\
&= \sum \operatorname{Im} c_j\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{Z}_j}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow, thank you very much Daniel Fischer! Your ANS make me very easy to understand it.